# trying to figure out why the function isn't working

Tags: javascript

I've written a filter function, which should filter the array of objets and it really filters it, but resulting variable doesn't get the filtered array.

examples of array:

```
hotels: [{
  photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png",
  name: "Hotel Moscow Name",
  address: "Moscow, some street, 1",
  amenities: [{
      name: 'wi-fi'
    }, {
      name: 'bar'
    }, {
      name: 'pool'
    }, {
      name: 'transfer'
    },
    {
      name: 'bath'
    }, {
      name: 'breakfast'
    }, {
      name: 'spa'
    }
  ],
  price: 3000
},
{
  photo: "/some_address/some_photo.png",
  name: "Hotel  St.Pitersberg Name",
  address: "sSt.Pitersberg, some street, 2",
  amenities: [{
      name: 'wi-fi'
    }, {
      name: 'bar'
    }, {
      name: 'fitness'
    }, {
      name: 'transfer'
    },
    {
      name: 'bath'
    }, {
      name: 'breakfast'
    }, {
      name: 'spa'
    }
  ],
  price: 4000
},
}]
```

```
changeFilterValue: function(choosenAmenity) {
    this.changeFiltersList(choosenAmenity);
    let settedList = this.settedFilters;

    this.filteredData = this.hotels.filter(function(hotel) { //массив hotels
      let amenityArray = [];
      hotel.amenities.forEach(function(amenity) {
        amenityArray.push(amenity.name);
      })
      return settedList.filter(function(elem) {
        console.log(settedList, amenityArray);
        console.log(amenityArray.includes(elem));
        return amenityArray.includes(elem);
      });
    })
    console.log(this.filteredData);
```

Comment: A `filter()` callback should not contain a `return ….filter(…);`. That's not going to remove anything from the outer array.

Answer (score 1):

`settedList.filter(...)` returns some array, which is always [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) . Try `return settedList.filter(...).length` instead if you want to check if array is not empty

Comment: Vlad, Glazov, thank you very much! it's really works! albeit only check if one of settedList array contains in amenities, and not everyone(